# Export audio from PowerPoint using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint

Tags: c#, powerpoint, office-interop

I have to convert all audio files in a presentation from .mp3 format to waves format. I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint to read all slides. I can access audio shapes.

My approach is to download all .mp3 files and convert them to waves using below approach and the import waves audio back in the slide.

```
using NAudio.Wave;
namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        using (var reader = new MediaFoundationReader(@"D:\Media1.mp3"))
        {
            WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(@"D:\Media1_wav.wav", reader);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I export audio files from PowerPoint using Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint?

Answer (score 0):

I could not find anything in interop library. So I converted my PowerPoint to zip file .Open the zip file. Under media folder, I copied .mp3 files in a new folder. Then I used naudio to convert mp3 to waves.